# Image squished on the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

I was working on my website and when trying to make all the images on there responsive, I found that the bottom image was squished? The bottom image does an animation where it slides down but is now squished. Is there anyway to fixed it?

Thanks, Aidan Cheung
[image: Website as of now]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>aidancheung.com</title>
</head>
<link href="file:///C|/Users/User/Downloads/aidancheung.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
 
 h1 {
  font-family: coolvetica;
  text-align: center;
}


</style>

<img src="Website.png" alt="Top Building" class="responsive">
<h1 style="line-height:3vw;font-size: 8vw;">aidancheung.<br><i style="font-size: 4vw">portfolio</i></br></h1>

<div class="bottom">
  <a href="aidancheung.htm" class="button centered">home</a>
  <img src="bottom.png" alt="Bottom Building" class="responsive">
</div>
</html>
```

```css
.bottom {
  position: relative;
  padding: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.bottom img {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 2s ease-out;
}

.bottom:hover img {
  top: 100%;
}
.button {
    display: block;
    width: 9em;
    height: 0.25em;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
 font-family: coolvetica;
 font-size: 30px;
  border-top: 0.05em solid black;
  border-right: 0.5em solid black;
  border-bottom: 1em solid black;
  border-left: 0.5em solid black;


}
.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `.bottom img {}` declaration you set the height of the image to 100% and in `.responsive {}` you set the width to 100% (both relative to the parent container). So it could easily be getting squeezed. Try `height: auto;` instead of 100%. However, the `max-height: 100%` in `.responsive` will actually keep squeezing the image if the 'natural' height of the image should be larger (given the width of the image and the ratio). So remove that line.

OR

Use a transparent pixel image and set the image as background and using `background-size: cover` to let it fill the container. In this case you should set the images width and height to 100% to fill the parent.

CSS

```
.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(bottom.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

HTML

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Bottom Building" class="responsive">
```